# Visibility in Kotlin coroutines

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines

I decided to dive in into Kotlin coroutines. I have some questions regarding visibility. I understand that in absence of a `ContinuationInterceptor`, it is possible different sections of the same coroutines to be executed by different threads.

How is guaranteed that, after a suspension, the new thread has the correct visibility of the coroutine internal state ?

For example:

```
    suspend fun doPost(customRatings : Map<String, Int>) : Int {...}

    fun postRatings_1() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val mutableMap : MutableMap<String, Int> = mutableMapOf()

            mutableMap["Apple"] = 1
            mutableMap["Banana"] = 2

            // ...

            val postId = doPost(mutableMap)

            // How am I guaranteed to see the two entries here ?
            println("posted ${mutableMap} with id ${postId}") 
        }
    }
```

Similarly when a new coroutine is launched

```
    fun postRatings_2() {

        val mutableMap : MutableMap<String, Int> = mutableMapOf()

        mutableMap["Apple"] = 1
        mutableMap["Banana"] = 2


        GlobalScope.launch {
            // How am I guaranteed to see the two entries here ?
            val postId = doPost(mutableMap)
            //...
        }
```

In both of these cases there is some mutable state shared between two (existing) threads.

I am looking for the "Happens-before" rule that guarantees that the mutable state will be properly visible by the two threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am looking for the "Happens-before" rule that guarantees that the mutable state will be properly visible by the two threads.

The guarantees come quite easily: for example if your dispatcher is based on a Java thread pool, the thread pool on its own already gives this guarantee. The code preceding the `executor.submit()` call *happens-before* the submitted code and that code, in turn, *happens-before* the code that observes the completion of the associated future.

Even if you use the null-dispatcher, called `Dispatchers.Unconfined`, which simply resumes the coroutine on whichever thread you happen to call `continuation.resume(result)`, you still get *happens-before* because the underlying framework which invokes your callback guarantees it.

You'd have to go pretty far in writing a custom broken `Dispatcher` implementation to mess up the ordering.